# Are extension methods an object-oriented feature of C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Do extension methods follow the object-oriented paradigm in C#?

Is it a good practice to use extension methods?

In the software development lifecycle how should we consider this question in the design phase?

Comment: Sounds like "if it is not OO, we shouldn't use it".

Comment: Noise - This has been asked lots of times on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are not an object oriented language feature. (compared to: classes, inheritance, polymorphism etc).

Like every language feature, it should be used where it is appropriate and for what it is designed for. There are already dozens of questions about when and how to use Extension methods.

- [What are the best practices for using Extension Methods in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-extension-methods-in-net)
- [Possible overuses of Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169422/possible-overuses-of-extension-methods)
- [Do Extension Methods Hide Dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296953/do-extension-methods-hide-dependencies)

Answer (score 10):

Eric Lippert has [blogged about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/10/28/the-future-of-c-part-two.aspx) and I suspect I can't do much better than to quote him:

> So, yes, the oft-heard criticism that
>   "extension methods are not
>   object-oriented" is entirely correct,
>   but also rather irrelevant. Extension
>   methods certainly are not
>   object-oriented. They put the code
>   that manipulates the data far away
>   from the code that declares the data,
>   they cannot break encapsulation and
>   talk to the private state of the
>   objects they appear to be methods on,
>   they do not play well with
>   inheritance, and so on. They're
>   procedural programming in a convenient
>   object-oriented dress.
>
> They're also incredibly convenient and
>   make LINQ possible, which is why we
>   added them. The fact that they do not
>   conform to some philosophical ideal of
>   what makes an object-oriented language
>   was not really much of a factor in
>   that decision.

I would add, however, that they're useful beyond just LINQ - for the same reason that they're useful *in* LINQ. It's really nice to be able to express algorithms which work on arbitrary implementations of a particular interface (such as `IEnumerable<T>` in LINQ to Obhects). Such algorithms typically don't have any context beyond the interfaces you're working on, so they're often naturally static.

If you accept that you've got some static utility method, which syntax would you rather use?

```
// Traditional
CollectionUtils.Sort(collection);

// Extension methods
collection.Sort();
```

The latter is simply more readable in my opinion. It concisely expresses what you want to do. It doesn't make it clear *how* you want to do it, but that's less important for *most* of the time - and more important when you're debugging that particular line, of course.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to it.

1. Is it OO when we use it
   No; it makes you feel that you are calling method on the particular type
2. Is it OO based on how it is compiled/built

Yes; Compiled code has a static method using the object on which extension method was invoked

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are just a language feature. They work on object instances and are very nice tool.

Consider them as a different way to extend class functionality. You can add new functionality to a class:

- By adding a partial class declaration. The class then instantly gets a bunch of new methods  and properties.
- By including a namespace with your extension methods holder class. The class then gets a bunch of new methods again.

Rather an organizational / language feature. Does not break object-oriented concept in any way. Just as header/source file division in C/C++ has nothing to do with object-orientation, just a language/framework feature.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Extension methods are just a tool. They can be very useful when used appropriately. But if you use them too much, it can obscure your code.

Answer (score 0):

Extension Methods are just static methods that work with a specific Class or Class Hierarchy. Python is OO but has modules, Ruby has mixins. I see it more as a language feature. I am pretty sure its still OO friendly