# extension function in a kotlin using super

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

How to call extension function of the base class in a derived class using the super keyword?

I tried to call using super but it doesn't work.

```
 open class abc {
     open fun aa() {
         println("function in abc")
     }
 }
 fun abc.sum() {
     println("extension function")
 }
 class ab: abc() {

     override fun aa() {
         super.aa()
         println("functon in ab")
     }
     fun sum() {
         super.sum()
         println("sum function")
     }
 }
 fun main(args: Array < String > ) {
     var aa: ab = ab()
     aa.aa()
     aa.aa()
     aa.sum()
 }
```

Here is the 16th number line error comes, I can't call the extension function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you created the extension out of the class it is no more member of that class. You are able to call `super.aa()` as it is the member of the `abc` class.

In order to use that method you have to call it in following way.

```
open class abc {
    open fun aa() {
        println("function in abc")
    }
}
fun abc.sum() {
    println("extension function")
}
class ab: abc() {

    override fun aa() {
        super.aa()
        println("functon in ab")
    }
    fun sum() {
        (this as abc).sum()
        println("sum function")
    }
}
fun main(args: Array < String > ) {
    var aa: ab = ab()
    aa.aa()
    aa.aa()
    aa.sum()
}
```

For more info refer this [link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/allow-extensions-to-override-member-functions-in-selected-cases/6294)

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code as these are not searchable.

Comment: @DavidRawson Just showing the output of the code given in the question.

Comment: Sorry , i have done mistake , make a sum function as shown here.  fun sum() {
         super.sum()
         println("sum function")
     }

Answer (score 12):

This will do:

```
(this as abc).sum()
```

`super` does not work as extension functions are not members of the base class to be overridden in derived classes.

Answer (score 3):

This type of namespace conflict is a general drawback of extension methods. Extension methods are essentially static and [do not mix well with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802380/are-extension-methods-an-object-oriented-feature-of-c).

In your particular case, there doesn't seem to be a need for the function `sum` to be an extension method. If you change it to an `open` virtual method, you will be able to design better for inheritance and potential overriding in a subclass.

Comment: Now see my code fun sum() {
         super.sum()
         println("sum function")
     }  here aa() and sum() both are member function , we can call aa() using super then why we can't call the sum() ?