# How to call extension function via same name instance function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

For example

```
open class TestClass

fun TestClass.testFunc(): String = "ext"
```

now in another file I write:

```
import xx.xx.testFunc as rename

class OverTestClass : TestClass() {

    fun testFunc(): String {
        return "OverTestClass - " + rename()
    }
}
```

You can see I rename `TestClass.testFunc()` as `rename()` so I can call `TestClass.testFunc()` in `OverTestClass`. But this is not cool, what the way I want to is like this:

```
return "OverTestClass - " + super.testFunc()
```

Is it possible?

I know this problem is upside down，the reason I want to this is: I am writing a lib used both in java and kotlin, I don't want write java like:

```
XxxKt.func(obj)
```

I want to:

```
obj.func(func)
```

So I put `func` as an instance function. and implement directly by its "super" extension function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extension function in a kotlin using super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170152/extension-function-in-a-kotlin-using-super)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try up-casting to the TestClass:

```kotlin
class OverTestClass : TestClass() {

    fun testFunc(): String {
        return "OverTestClass - " + (this as TestClass).testFunc()
    }
}
```