# Extension Methods vs. Regular Methods - Best Practice Ideas

Tags: c#

I'm having a bit of a difficult time determining when to implement a method as an extension method and when to implement a method as a stand-alone method. What are some best practices people follow in determining this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use an extension method if any of the following conditions are true:

- You need a method on a type and you don't own the source.
- You need a method on a type, you *do* own the source, and the type is an interface.
- You need a method on a type, you *do* own the source, but adding the method creates undesired coupling.*

Otherwise, you should use a real method on the actual type itself.

I don't think it makes a whole lot of sense to create an extension method for a class or struct that you own the source for - why confuse readers with an extension method when a regular method will suffice?

**Suggested reading:** [Framework Design Guidelines: Extension Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/01/12/framework-design-guidelines-extension-methods.aspx)

* *Imagine that you wanted to add convenience methods to a type but don't want to create dependencies to assemblies or types that shouldn't be part of the API.  You could use extension methods to manage this.*

Comment: One other case i would add: You need a method on a type, you own the source but the method would otherwise create a coupling that is not desired.

Comment: The suggested reading link is dead, I was not able to find a substitute.

Answer (score 3):

[Try this Stackoverflow post for a discussion about extension method best practices.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-extension-methods-in-net)

From my perspective I use extension methods when I have a lot of utility functions for a particular type.

I find that...

```
string.ExtensionMethod();
```

looks cleaner than...

```
StringHelper.ExtensionMethod("string to do something with");
```

Comment: But not when you weren't the person who wrote ```ExtensionMethod()```, and spend some time trying to find ```ExtensionMethod``` in the official C# docs only to realize that you were looking in the wrong place.